# Control key + character not being handled in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In attempting to listen to a user click the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key (paste) in an input field, we've run into a problem getting IE to handle that event.

I want this solution to be cross-browser compatible.

The code we're using is cross-browser capable and yet we run into an issue ONLY when holding down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key in Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="mytest" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
      var main_box = document.getElementById('mytest');
      window.addEventListener('keypress', 
        function(evt)
        {
          evt = evt || window.event;
          var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
          var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
          if(evt.ctrlKey && (charStr == 'v' || charStr == 'V'))
          {
            alert("CTRL+V pressed.");               
          }
        }
      );
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix the issue with IE?

Comment: So... what's the issue then?

Comment: Also I don't think it's a very good idea to try to intercept events the operating system also handles at a much lower level than your app. I'd consider either using nonconflicting shortcuts, or watching for changes to the value of the input fields. If the browser isn't obligated to report any and all keystrokes to Javascript code, then your code is not in fact supposed to be "cross-browser" to begin with.

Comment: Also there's an actual `paste` event you could handle instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onpaste (despite the MDN link this should work in IEs.)

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',
function(evt)
{
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if(evt.ctrlKey && (charStr == 'v' || charStr == 'V'))
    {
        alert("CTRL+V pressed.");               
    }
}, false );
```

**[Note:](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)** The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for all keys.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/FuxRy/)